# Is there a way to tell when a time-series can no longer be predicted by the same model?

Tags: regression, time-series, anomaly-detection, change-point, dynamic-regression

I am modeling a time series using a multiple (dynamic) linear regression model. I suspect that at some point, the model no longer accurately predicts the true series. Is there a way to find the point where the true series and the model diverge?

Ideally I'm looking for an already implemented R-package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an R package called `changepoint.forecast` available on Github [here](https://github.com/grundy95/changepoint.forecast).  It implements online changepoint models which look at the forecast residuals and check for changes within them, mainly changes/drift in the expectation and variance.  It can be used with any model that produces forecasts which are expected to capture the mean and second-order structure (variance/autocovariance) of the data, including black boxes.

The package will be released on CRAN when the paper is further along the publication pipeline (it was submitted earlier this year).  There is a talk describing the functionality [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-rThN8ktT4).

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. Absolutely incredible that you found that.